# Get location from coordinates and placing them in a widget flutter geocoding

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding

So I already have my coordinates and now I just want to call my function to convert those coordinates into a real location.
I am using this function from geocoding package.

```
 Future<void> getfieldlocation() async {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    Address address = await geoCode.reverseGeocoding(
        latitude: _locationData.latitude as double,
        longitude: _locationData.longitude as double);

    setState(() {
      fieldLatitude = _locationData.latitude;
      fieldLogitude = _locationData.longitude;
      addressCity = address.city;
    });
  }
```

Now suppose I want to place that result into my widget:

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var loc = getUserLocation(widget.lat, widget.long);

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("Adoption Form"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
                Text(loc)]
  )))}
```

but I am getting : null

Answer (score 0):

There is a must to use a map service to be able to show any map location.
For example, using google maps api to convert those coordinates to a real location on the map. 
 
For more information read the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding

Comment: As far as I know, geocoder package has its own data class where you can find city, address etc based on the coordinates that you pass to the function reverseGeocoding. I just wanted to know if there was an error in my code. Btw I am using Tomtom Maps service to display those points in a map